# Centering DIV that resizes with window

Tags: css, html, centering

I've exhausted myself on this topic and I just feel it's more simple than it seems.
This site: http://ryanfeerer.com/ if you look at the content section it stays center aligned when making the window smaller or larger. 
I'm creating a site that is very similar in DW CS6 and I have my tiled background set and have created a DIV to essentially hover over the background. Basically just like the site referenced.

Is there not a simple CSS code that would do this? This seems like such a simple concept ha.

Thanks in advance and super sorry if this has been answered numerous times. I tried to do my research but to no avail.

Nate

Comment: the effect on that site, is called `responsive web design`. it's not easy to implement. but if you just want to center the container, just follow the answer by @RHarrington.

Answer (score 2):

What I do to create a center div is to align it using percentages from the left and the right. That way it responds to the size of the browser. Example

```
#content{
left:15%;
right:15%;
top:0px;
bottom:0px;
}
```

Although this will mean that when the browser window is very thin your content will get squished up because it will always maintain the 15% either side.

Comment: unless you also include min-width:500px; for example

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Ah, I misinterpreted what you were asking.  I see now, that when you resize the page, all the content shrinks including the images.  I would look into a jQuery/javascript solution.

Comment: max-width should be better.

Comment: Ok, I'm sort of new to web designing, can anyone share a link that would help me in that realm?